# How can I export data from SimpleDB to Excel or TextPad?

Tags: sql, amazon-simpledb

I want to export data from SimpleDB to Excel or TextPad. How can I write a query for exporting data?

Thanks,

Senthil

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SDB Explorer](http://gallery.sdbexplorer.com/displayimage-4.html) to export the data into a CSV file, which you can open with your favorite editor.

[image]

Comment: i use the SDB Explorer  in my systems(using my key) it's not containing our domains,... please tell how can i use SDB explorer

Comment: Hmm... I've successfully used it not too long ago. There must be something wrong with your config.  I recommend contacting the developers of SDB Explorer or using the boto SDB tool (https://code.google.com/p/boto/wiki/SimpleDbIntro) to generate a CSV file manually.

Comment: @The Alchemist - you say "into a CSV file", but the screenshot and my version of SDB Explorer only support XML, not CSV (which could be imported into Excel) nor Excel.  True that XML is a text format that can be opened by TextPad, but probably not what the OP meant.

Answer (score 1):

[Sdbport](https://github.com/brettweavnet/sdbport) is a Ruby Gem that can export / import SimpleDB domains.  It works across accounts and regions. It can be used as a class or stand alone CLI.

On a system with Ruby intalled (tested with 1.9.3p125):

**Install sdbport:**

gem install sdbport

**Set your AWS credentials:**

export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your_aws_key
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your_aws_secret

**Export SimpleDB domain from us-west-1:**

sdbport export -a $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -s $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -r us-west-1 -n data -o /tmp/test-domain-dump

**Import into domain in us-east-1**

sdbport import -a $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -s $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -r us-west-1 -n data -i /tmp/test-domain-dump

Answer (score 0):

You can Export your content of domain in XML using SDB Explorer. 
[For more details please refer our documentation page and for watch video.](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/documentation/simpledb--how-to-export-domain.html)

**Disclosure**: I'm a developer of SDB Explorer.

Comment: SDB Explorer version 2009.02.03.01 has a bug where it omits cols (attributes) from the exported XML.  For example, if you have a domain with most of the attributes you use absent from the first batch of items, SDB Explorer will not show the attribute names on the left panel, despite showing them in the results pane.  Upon export, the XML only contains the attributes shown in the left panel, not all of the attributes present in the domain (which omits most of them for the domain I attempted to export).

Comment: SDB Explorer version 2011.09.01.02 correctly exports all attributes to XML.

Comment: Thanks David for your research. Truly speaking even we (developer team of sdbexplorer) not aware of this issue. Thanks once again. We appreciate customer feedback and it is a priority for us to listen to & resolve your concerns.

Comment: @AshishPancholi: Please take care when promoting your product, see the respective FAQ [May I promote products or websites I am affiliated with here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) for details.

Comment: @Steffen Opel Thanks for the information. I will take care from next time. Thanks again

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio you can install AWS explorer extension this will give you the ability to do queries against the simpleDb and then export the query result set to csv file by one click